# What's the right way to display values from the server?

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript, socket.io, ionic2

I took the chat example and try to display other stuff in my app via Socket.io from the server but I can't figure out this behaviour, I'll try to explain as best as I can, on the server side part I'm trying to push a simple integer value to my client app:

```
var socket = require('socket.io'),
    http = require('http'),
    server = http.createServer(),
    socket = socket.listen(server);
    var msgProva = 2;

socket.on('connection', function(connection) {
    console.log('User Connected');
    socket.emit('prova', msgProva); //2


    connection.on('message', function(msg){
        socket.emit('message', msg);
    });

});

server.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server started');
});
```

as you can see I'm trying to push a simple "2".

This is my home.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
  socket:any
  chat_input:string;
  chats = [];
  prova;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
      this.socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

   this.socket.on('message', (msg) => {
     console.log("message", msg);
     this.chats.push(msg);
   });

   this.socket.on('prova', (msgProva) => {
       console.log("msgProva", msgProva);
       this.prova.push(msgProva);
   });
  }

  send(msg) {
        if(msg != ''){
            this.socket.emit('message', msg);
        }
        this.chat_input = '';
    }
}
```

So I'm expecting that on "prova" event I recive my "2" from the server.

And this is my home.html:

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon name="logo-twitter" item-left></ion-icon>
    Followers
    <ion-badge color="secondary">{{prova}}</ion-badge>
  </ion-item>

    <ion-list>
      <ion-item *ngFor="let message of chats">{{message}}</ion-item>
    </ion-list>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="chat_input" placeholder="Enter message"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>

    <button ion-button block (click)="send(chat_input)">Send</button>
</ion-content>
```

but so far I'm not able to see where the problem is, so please be patient with my vague question, as I don't know exactly where the problem is, can anyone point me or explain what I'm obviously doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be that `prova` is `undefined`, yet you are attempting to push to it.

```
export class HomePage {
  socket:any
  chat_input:string;
  chats = [];
  prova = []; // set to an array
```

Comment: I think I have already tried that..I'm thinking that my problem is in the html file, as it prints the value "2" also in the {{message}}

Comment: In your HTML file, you are trying to echo out `prova` and loop through `chats`. In your TS file, you are attempting to `push` a value onto both `this.prova` and `this.chats`. 

As far as I can tell, seeing "2" in the `message` would be correct, because you've pushed it into the array and you loop through it.

Comment: @SteamDev Ok, sorry for the delay on my replay, you are right I didn't initialiazed prova as an array, I though it was possible to push a number but apparently this.prova.push can only push arrays.. is there a way to pass just one variable instead of an array??

Comment: @FabioEnne you could always just set the value of `this.prova` in your `socket.on('prova')` listener. (i.e. change `this.prova.push(msgProva);` to `this.prova = msgProva;`)